# C# Create Task and Add to List<Task>

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I have a loop that has to compare distances between 30,000 or so points.  My code is as follows and it's slow:

```
static Task<Location> GetClosestSpotAsync(Location Spot)
{
    Location closest = new();

    List<Location> list = Db.Locations.Where(l => l.MapId == Spot.MapId &&
                                l.ZoneId == Spot.ZoneId).ToList();

    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    if (list.Count > 0)
    {
        double distance = 1000;
        foreach (Location l in list)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                if (Spot.DistanceToOtherWaypoint(list, Spot) < distance)
                    closest = l;
            });

        }
    }
    LogMaker.Log(closest.ToString());
    return Task.FromResult(closest);
}
```

What I think I should do is create an array of Tasks with each being a distance comparison and then do a WhenAll to run the comparisons in parallel.  But I can't find the syntax to make a Task wrapper for

```
if (Spot.DistanceToOtherWaypoint(list, Spot) < distance) { closest = l; }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: first you should add the task.run to the list of tasks. like this -> tasks.Add(Task.Run( () => { .... })); then at end you run you list of tasks -> Task t = Task.WhenAll(tasks);  try {
          t.Wait();
       }
       catch {}

Comment: Spinning up multiple tasks with only one distance calculation, will take longer than singlethreaded i guess. Try to batch them.

Comment: Thanks for the syntax Amjad - it works.

Comment: Joroen, you are correct - it's slower than singlethreaded.  I'm not sure what you mean by batch the comparisons?

Comment: By batching, you would compare given spot with the sub-set of your total list, say 1000. so that you will only need to do 30 parallel tasks. that is much better than doing thousands of parallel tasks.

Comment: Have you considered using the `Parallel.ForEach` method or the PLINQ library instead?

Comment: I tried that too Theodor.  Thanks for suggeston.  I've also tried batching. All 4 methods come in at around the same time.  I may need to re-think how I have designed the app.

Thanks all.